# Folium Heatmap with color bar Values

Tags: python, heatmap, colorbar, folium

In my project I receive a DataFrame with scores for cities in the US. I can plot the HeatMap using Folium however I would like to add a colorbar to showcase the numerical values of these scores, based on the color of the HeatMap. Is there a way to do it?.
My code so far

```
cities = pd.read_csv ('../datasets/us.csv'))

cord = cities [["latitude","longitude","score"]]

#create map
base_map = folium.Map(
    width =  "100%",
    height = "100%",
    location = [-15.788497,-47.879873],
    zoom_start = 4
        )


base_map = base_map.add_child(plugins.HeatMap(cord,radius = 20, min_opacity = 0.1))
```

Comment: Since the folium heatmap changes colors according to density, it does not match the colors specified in the color map. If the answer is to simply add a colormap to the heatmap, it can be done. Do you need an answer?

Comment: @r-beginners Different person here, would love to see how you would approach this!